# Removing badge from iOS app icon

Tags: ios, iphone, badge

In this application that I'm trying to make, I use push notifications. This part works just fine. When I send a notification I also add a badge to the app icon. The problem is when I lunch the application it should disappear again, but it does not.

```
-(IBAction)Push{

    NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [data setObject:@"Numfeud: Troels made a move!" forKey:@"alert"];

    [data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"badge"];

    [data setObject:@"bar" forKey:@"foo"];

    [PFPush sendPushDataToChannelInBackground:@"GameChannel2" withData:data];
}
```

In the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I try to set badge to 0 in this way:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

How can I clear the application icon badge?

Answer (score 215):

If your app becomes active again and is still in the background you should reset the badge count in `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` as well:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

If your app is still running in the background `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` won't be called.

Comment: Thanks made! Then there is something there make sense :) Works just find, I'm only reset it in the BecomeActive method. Can't se why I should have it twice?

Comment: Resetting once in the ``-applicationDidBecomeActive:`` will do just fine. Because this method will also be called when ``-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`` is called. Please accept my answer :)

Comment: Isn't it better to do it on applicationWillResignActive, right before the user is going to see it?

Answer (score 8):

Likely, `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is not being called, because your app is still running in the background. In order to remove the badge count when the app is launched from the background you'll have to reset the badge number in `-applicationWillEnterForeground:`, too.

Comment: Thanks Fabian! Your answer was just what i needed :) thannnkkss

Comment: Are -applicationDidBecomeActive and -applicationWillEnterForeground: doing the same less or more? When placing the reset in -applicationDidBecomeActive. It work i both situations.

Comment: -applicaionDidBecomeActive: will be invoked when returning from a phone call, too. -applicationWillEnterForeground: is the appropriate method in your situation.

Comment: applicationWillEnterForeground will not be called after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, though.

Comment: Yes, that's why it has to be reset twice. Using `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` and only resetting it once is okay, too.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift and In AppDelegate

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can use this codes also.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

or In a specific ViewController

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe call it in `applicationWillResignActive` (in `AppDelegate.m`):

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

This will help you to clear `badge` if `push` come when app is being open. User seeing `notification` and you clear it, when he press `Home Button` (once or twice). Also it will be clear if `app` being `closed` (clear after user open it).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880910/5297305) you can see when this method called.