# Is applicationWillResignActive ever called before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ends?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate

Can a scenario happen where `applicationWillResignActive:` will be called before `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` **ends**?

Basically, can I count on `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to always be **done** before `applicationWillResignActive` is triggered for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple's *[iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7)* in the "App States and Multitasking" Section, indicates `applicationWillResignActive:` is called as part of your application's handling of events through processing the run loop, which only begins after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` has finished.

Furthermore, application lifecycle events always happen on the main thread, so it wouldn't be possible for one of them to pre-empt the other or run in parallel with each other.

Answer (score 44):

Yes `-application:didFinishLaunching:` will always be called before `-applicationWillResignActive:`

See this image for more detail:

[image]

Comment: awesome image is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The runloop can be called recursively.

A hypothetical implementation of `application:disFinishLaunchigWithOptions:` could run the runloop which, in turn, would allow for notification delivery from within the method.

The following contrived example would let the run loop run, yet never return:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    while (YES)
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of such implementation?

Comment: Thanks. However, that's really hypothetical probably

Comment: @Dk222 I've seen implementations do this, for instance apps that download content from a server before displaying anything. I generally advise against polling the runloop, though.