# Asymmetry in connect/disconnect in GCM iOS example

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

In the [GCM client guide for iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client), it shows you to call `[[GCMService sharedInstance] connectWithHandler:...]` in `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`, and later it shows you to call `[[GCMService sharedInstance] disconnect];` in `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

The placement of connect and disconnect seems asymmetric to me. Is there a reason it is done this way? I feel that it should either be

- Connect in `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` and disconnect in `-applicationWillResignActive:`, or
- Connect in `-applicationWillEnterForeground:` and disconnect in `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Execution States for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3) in Apple's App Programming Guide for iOS, it states that:

*`applicationWillResignActive`:—Lets you know that your app is transitioning away from being the foreground app. Use this method to put your app into a quiescent state.*

Compare to

*`applicationDidEnterBackground`:—Lets you know that your app is now running in the background and may be suspended at any time.*

For example, if you press the Home button of your device **twice**, the `applicationWillResignActive` method will be call immediately, your app is in a `transitioning` state now. see the image below (**Your app leave foreground, but not yet in background**):

[image]

If you select other app, the `applicationDidEnterBackground` of your app will be called, and your app enters background. So it is better to call `GCMService.sharedInstance().disconnect()` when your app is actually in a `background` state compared to a `transitioning` state.

---

Similarly, `applicationWillEnterForeground` vs `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

If you are in other app now, and you switch back to your own app, the `applicationWillEnterForeground` will be called immediately, but your app is might still in **an inactive state(which is currently not receiving events)**.

It might only last for less than half a second, and `applicationDidBecomeActive` will called immediately after. Because `applicationWillEnterForeground` is more a `transitioning` state. So it is better to call `GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler()`  when your app is actually in **an active state(app is running in the foreground and is receiving events)**.

---

You might think `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` are asymmetric, but these two methods all have a word `Did`. But two other methods have the word `Will`, which means a `transitioning` state.

You can also see the Life Cycle picture from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880910/4195406).

**Edit after @user102008's comment**:

If you do connect in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method, then connect method wont be called when the app is first launched. Also, the GCM doc says that `Call disconnect when the client app is in the background or when it needs to stop exponential background connection retry`, so I think its better to call disconnect when the app is in background, instead of when phone call comes? I think you can use enum with 3 different states `connecting` , `not connected` and `connected`, when the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method is called, you can check if its not `connected` or `connecting`, then you call the connect method again.

Comment: But if you go from active to inactive (e.g. if a dialog pops up, or a call comes, or you press Home twice), and back to active, then you will have done connect twice, with no disconnect in between (because it never went into background).

Comment: @user102008, you have a good point, I also edit my answer, because comment only allow certain amount of characters.