# Push notification badge reset count

Tags: ios, push-notification, reset, badge

I'm using PushBot as my push notification service, my issue is how do I reset the badge count. I've search and read to use this line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

The only way the badge count gets reset is if I quit the app from running on the mulit-task bar and launch the app again, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: When do you want to clear the badge count?

Comment: I want to clear the badge count when the app is launched again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just make a button on your UI and on his action put the code line:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

It will reset it.

Take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9557252/529543) for some other implementations.

Answer (score 15):

To clear the badge count whenever the application becomes active, simply include your line of code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

In the `AppDelegate.m` file's `applicationDidBecomeActive` delegate method.

`applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is only called on the initial launch, and does not get called again when the application goes to the background and back to the foreground.

Comment: This appears to be working, but the next time I receive a a notification, the count isn't 1. It's the count that was removed + 1 (the total notification count since the app was installed). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm also getting "count that was removed" + 1.  Any help?  I've put that code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` AND `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Are you talking about the badge number in a remote notification? That's up to you to set on the server when you send the remote notification.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 3.0

```
//AppleDelgate.swift
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        //....
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
       //....
}
```