# IconBadgeNumber still appear, nevertheless removed IconBadgeNumber description

Tags: ios, objective-c, badge

The problem is IconBadgeNumber "1" still appear.

I have removed all `applicationIconBadgeNumber` description,
removed the app and built again.
nonetheless Icon Badge Number still appear.

Why do such problem occur?

Comment: Could you post your code regarding scheduling the local notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the badge number by assigning the applicationIconBadgeNumber property of the notification to 0.

Taken from the [Apple Developer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1):

(When your app is in the background)

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    NSString *itemName = [notif.userInfo objectForKey:ToDoItemKey];
    [viewController displayItem:itemName];  // custom method
    app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber - 1;
}
```

and when your app is being launched:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)opts {
    // check launchOptions for notification payload and custom data, set UI context
    [self startDownloadingDataFromProvider];  // custom method
    app.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    // other setup tasks here....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be a duplicate, be sure to check out [Removing badge from iOS app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557132/removing-badge-from-ios-app-icon)

Next time, try to do some research before asking please.