# iPhone app showing "1" near app icon

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have created a new iPhone app using objective-c (no phonegap etc.). When I am installing it on an iPhone 5 / iPhone 6 (iOS8), it is showing a `1`, as if there was a notification, on the top right corner of the app icon immediately after its installation. Why is this and how can I remove it?

The app uses push notifications, but immediately after installation there should be no notification for the app.

Comment: You probably had a badge count of `1` before you uninstalled the app. iOS doesn't appear to reset this when you delete the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you want reset app badge number to 0 ?

try:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];`

[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557132/removing-badge-from-ios-app-icon/9557252#9557252)

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you had some badge set to the app & your removed the app from the device. So the best thing is that to change the application badge to `nil` in `appDidFinishLaunchWithOptions`.

Compile & create a build, Install app. Run it once. you will have the badge removed by then. Then just remove that extra line you have added in `appDidFinishLaunchWithOptions`.