# How to reset the notification badge number in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I can't reset my notification badge number for next notification after open previous notification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing badge from iOS app icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557132/removing-badge-from-ios-app-icon)

Answer (score 3):

Write this code at

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Register notification before it calls

```
UIUserNotificationSettings * notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the badge number from the app itself as follows :

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

By setting the value as 0, you are resetting the badge number

To update the badge number via push, you need to include the following in your payload:

```
"badge" : 0
```