# Conditionally dismiss remote notification from didReceiveRemoteNotification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My target is to run iOS app in background by receiving silent-pushes and post `UILocalNotifications` with some data downloaded from internet and decrypted inside app. I did it using method `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` and pushing empty silent notifications from my server when some data is available to client.

But if user force closes app - this method is not called at all. And user is not notified about something available for him.

Then I added some text to push notification. So some time it all works as I want, but several hours later it become to show 2 notifications for 1 event. First - visible but not sensitive notification from server and local notification with sensitive data.

I just wanna always download data by push and show local notification and when my app is force closed - show just a notification that "something" happens.

UPDATE:

Looks like my question is closely related to [Will iOS launch my app into the background if it was force-quit by the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068762/will-ios-launch-my-app-into-the-background-if-it-was-force-quit-by-the-user)

The most strange thing is that: I did wanted behavior and it works for several hours. I don't know how exactly I achieved this, but here are my screenshots, where app was suspended and also was manually killed from switcher:

[image] [image]

I think it can be some kind of trick with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749035/440168 Because my code changed app badge. But may be this was an apple bug that it happens...